# Java split function gives me a small length of result String array

Tags: java, string, split

I have this code:

```
String string = "_a_b___";
String[] parts = string.split("_");
```

The result is that variable parts has only three elements

```
parts[0] = ""
parts[1] = "a" 
parts[2] = "b"
```

This is weird, because there are five "_" chars, so after splitting there should be six elements, not only three of them.

I want

```
parts[0] = ""
parts[1] = "a"
parts[2] = "b"
parts[3] = ""
parts[4] = "" 
parts[5] = ""
```

How to do that? Thank you very much!

Comment: Just curious, why would you want the last three empty strings?

Comment: Because sometime I split "\_a_b___" and sometime "x_a_b_c_d_e". Then I use parts[5] and in the first case it throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Oh, when I split, I play with the data at hand. Meaning, instead of using part[5]. I would using parts.length in a loop and do things accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution of @Zakir is correct, i would add another information to use it perfectly, to get what you want instead of using `split("_", 6)` you can generalize it and use :

```
String[] parts = string.split("_", string.replace("(?!_)", "").length());
```

Which can accept any length.

for `_a_b___` you will get `[, a, b, , , ]`

---

**Edit**

Or like @Bill F mention in comment,  you can also use `String[] parts = string.split("_", -1);` for any length as well. [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-)

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but you can also use `split("_", -1)` for any length as well. [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-)

Comment: you read deep deep @BillF this is correct you can also use `split("_", -1)` can i use this in my answer ?

Comment: thak you @BillF for your new information i appreciate it :) you can check my answer, feel free to edit it

Comment: Thanks! Just trying to help :) learn something new everyday :)

Answer (score 6):

From [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):-

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting
>   array.

Try`split("_",6)`

Comment: i like your solution you have my +1 it is a little not complete check my solution above

Comment: Nice.! Good find.

Comment: @YCF_L: Agree your ans is complete and elegant!